# How do I match valid words with a ruby regular expression

Tags: ruby, regex

Using a ruby regular expression, how do I match all words in a coma separated list, but only match if the *entire* word contains valid word characters (i.e.: letter number or underscore).  For instance, given the string:

> "see, jane, run, r#un, j@ne, r!n"

I would like to match the words

> 'see', 'jane' and 'run',

but not the words

> 'r#un', 'j@ne' or 'r1n'.

I do not want to match the coma ... just the words themselves.

I have started the regex here: http://rubular.com/regexes/12126

Comment: Is there any reason that you can't split the string into an array on the commas and then run each item through the regex you already have and see if you get 1 result back?  Anything with non-word characters would return multiple results.

Comment: I am using the regex as part of a route.  I don't think splitting into an array first is an option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
s="see, jane, run, r#un, j@ne, r!n, fast"
s.scan(/(?:\A|,\s*)(\w+)(?=,|\Z)/).flatten
# => ["see", "jane", "run", "fast"]
```

Answer (score 0):

another way

`result = s.split(/[\s,]/).select{|_w| _w =~ /^\w+$/}`